# WinForms - Any way to convert UI of Visual C++ project to Visual C#?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, winforms, porting

I'm now done with a .NET WinForms project in C++. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Express Edition.

So from my experience so far and after a little bit of research, I find C# to be more clean, easy and more popular way to make the best out of the .NET framework. I found many straight forward references online for many problems in C#, which I had to struggle to achieve in C++. Also, C# gives me faster builds and it has pretty easy resource management.

So for the above reasons, I'd really like to port my current C++ project to C#. I know I'll have to translate the logical code, but is there a way to take atleast my GUI, ie My Forms directly into the C#'s designer? Or am I only left with the option of Designing the whole UI again from scratch?

Any help will be very appreciated, Thanks a lot for taking your precious time for me.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a decompiler like [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) or [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/). You should be able to decompile your assemblies in C#. With little effort or much, depends how big your project is, you could switch from Managed C++ to C#. Some Decompiler Addins allows to completly write the assembly to disk.

But you lose information with this approach. Basically comments, sometimes you gain goto's, get some compiler generated stuff and so on. But with the InitializeComponent() Method you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you!. Decompilers are one way to approach. If no one comes up with g ways, I'll accept your answer..